# I can't change keys of the multi-dimensional array and explode its values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key, explode

I have an array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [creator] => a, b ) [1] => Array ( [creator] => c, d ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [creator] => e, f ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [creator] => g, h ) [1] => Array ( [creator] => i, j ) [2] => Array ( [creator] => k, l ) [3] => Array ( [creator] => m, n ) [4] => Array ( [creator] => o, p ) ) )
```

I want to change the name of all its keys from `[creator]` to `[author]` and have to explode its items into `[first]`, `[last]`

So the desired output should be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [author] => [first] => a [last] => b ) [1] => Array ( [author] => [first] => c [last] => d ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [author] => [first] => e [last] => f ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [author] => [first] => g [last] => h ) [1] => Array ( [author] => [first] => i [last] => j ) [2] => Array ( [author] => [first] => k [last] => l ) [3] => Array ( [author] => [first] => m [last] => n ) [4] => Array ( [author] => [first] => o [last] => p ) ) )
```

I have tried:

```
for($loop=0; $loop<sizeof($output); $loop++) {
     $authors[] = $output[$loop]['creators'];
}
$a123 = explode(', ', $authors);
foreach ($authors as $items) {
    foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
        $myarray[$k]['author'] = $v;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What you tried for getting the array you want, add your code in question.

Comment: @KaushaMehta Sorry, just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to iterate through each item of your array, exploding the `creator` value, creating the new `author` value using that data and then using `unset()` to remove the old `creator` value.

```
foreach($array AS $a => $b)
{
    foreach($b AS $c => $d)
    {
        $name = explode(', ', $d['creator']);
        $array[$a][$c]['author'] = array(
            'first' => $name[0],
            'last' => $name[1]
        );
        unset($array[$a][$c]['creator']);
    }
}
```

Code not tested, but should show the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, array formatting is working fine the only issue is the explode is not working as it should. The output of the code: $name = explode($d['creator'], ', '); should split the first, last name but instead its output is: Array ( [0] => , )   any ideas?

Comment: @KA - Sorry, silly mistake there - explode params are in wrong order.  Should be `$name = explode(', ', $d['creator']);`